# How to get field of a json object with jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a object with json format such as this . I want get id of field that has specific title for example id of italia is 1. I use this code but don't work.

```
for (var item in dataFlight) {
    if ("italia" == item.title) {
        $("#DepartureHidden").val(item.id);
    }
}
```

json object (dataFlight) :

```
[{"title":"italia,"id":"1","Iscity":"0"},{"title":"milan","id":"2","Iscity":"1"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop item is representing index not the value. You can use `each()` like following. BTW you have missed a double quote(") in your json.

```js
var dataFlight=[{"title":"italia","id":"1","Iscity":"0"},{"title":"milan","id":"2","Iscity":"1"}];
//------------------------------^------------
$.each(dataFlight, function() {
    if ("italia" == this.title) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```